# Java - Attach extra column from @ManyToMany relashionship to entity model

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, many-to-many

Scenario:

I have 3 tables on MySQL server thats interacting with @ManyToMany, everything is working as well, but I need to retrieve another column rather than the column named on @ManyToMany annotation, like:

```
Midias
|
|_ midiasId
|
|...
|@ManyToMany...
|_ veiculos


Veiculos
|
|_ veiculosId
|
|...
|
|@ManyToMany
|- midias
|...
|
|- bonus       <-  I like this variable here fetched from MidiaVeiculos table  and attached to Veiculos entity*

MidiaVeiculos
|
|- midiaCodigo
|- veiculoCodigo
|- bonus
```

I don't know if my code is fine, but I believe that have some other method more efficient, like:

```
veiculos.getBonus();
```

My code:

```
private List<MidiaResponseBonus> listarMidiasPorFiltros(BuscarMidiaRequest request) {

        List<MidiaModel> midias = this.mRepository.findAll(request.listarMidiasPorFiltros());

        List<MidiaResponseBonus> mb = midias.stream()
        .map(m -> {
            List<VeiculoResponseComBonus> veiculos = m.getVeiculos().stream().map(v -> new VeiculoResponseComBonus(
                v.getCodigo(),
                v.getNumeroOrdem(),
                v.getAnoFabricacao(),
                v.getEmpresa(),
                v.getRota(),
                v.getOperacional(),
                this.mvRepository.findByMidiaCodigoAndVeiculoCodigo(m.getCodigo(), v.getCodigo()).getBonus()
            )).collect(Collectors.toList());
            veiculos.forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.getBonus()));
            
            return new MidiaResponseBonus(
                m.getCodigo(),
                m.getCliente(),
                m.getCampanha(),
                m.getProduto(),
                m.getPedidoInsercao(),
                m.getPedidoProducao(),
                m.getInicioPeriodo(),
                m.getTerminoPeriodo(),
                m.getInicioFotos(),
                m.getTerminoFotos(),
                veiculos
            );
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return mb;
    }
```

I need to retrieve the bonus column on the midiaVeiculos table

Can I get some way with @ManyToOne and @OneToMany?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, `@ManyToMany`, `@OneToMany`, etc are all relations between Entities.   An `Entity A` could have a relation to `Entity B` through a specific attribute.

If you wanted your `Veiculos` to have knowledge about `bonus`, then you will need a `@OneToOne` relation to MidiaVeiculos:

```
@Entity
public class Veiculos{

 @OneToOne
 MidiVeiculous midi;

}

veiculos.getMidi().getBonus();
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html

---

Another option which could work is using SecondaryTable:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Veiculos")
@SecondaryTable(name = "MidiaVeiculos", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "MidiaVeiculos_id"))
class Veiculos{

    @Column(name = "bonus", table = "MidiaVeiculos")
    String bonus;

}
```

Still however, there must be a relation between the two tables.  Like a PK-FK of some kind.

See: **Mapping one entity to several tables**

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-join